# MarkLogic Ops Direct: Externally signed server certificate needed

Tags: cluster-computing, marklogic, monitor, certificate-authority

We have installed & configured Marklogic Ops Director to monitor MarkLogic cluster

We were able to configure manage cluster from Ops director, but not able to see details of Manage cluster details in Ops Director.

We checked and found below error in in TaskServer_ErrorLog.txt on Ops Director instance

> 2019-12-11 10:50:00.066 Info: Externally signed server certificate needed for machine name (Ops Director machine).

We checked configuration and Certificate Authority(ca) is configured correctly

`opsdirCa=generate`

I am not sure what is not configured correctly here, can you please help?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would suggest uninstalling & trying again.  Ensure all the values under option #1 in the properties file are filled out, and all the values under #2 & #3 are commented out.  Also make sure you select the correct CA when you add a server to Ops Director.  If that doesn't work, file a ticket with Support and we can look further into the issues you are encountering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ops Director uses PKI authentication to allow the Ops Director cluster to communicate with the Managed host safely and securely.  If you choose to generate a certificate, Ops Director creates a local CA, and a self signed certificate.  This CA must also be added to any other clusters that you wish to managed with Ops Director.

In this case it looks like the certificate that Ops Director is attempting to use to authenticate against the managed server is not correct.

First, check the `SecureManage` app server on the cluster  you are trying to manage (default is 8003).  Ensure that the following settings are correct:

- Authentication: Basic
- Internal Security: True
- External Security:  Should have an external security credential named `OpsDirectorSystem-[management-cluster-id#]`

Then check *Security --> External Credentials* and make sure the credential above is listed.

Check *Security --> Secure Credentials* and make sure that there is an entry for `opsdir-[managment-cluster-id#]` and that it is correct.  Verify that the certificate has the correct information for *issuer* and *subject*, and that the *target uri pattern* is set to `https://.*:8003/manage/.*`

Check *Security --> Certificate Authorities*, select the entry that says "*MarkLogic*" (not "Mark Logic" or "Marklogic Corporation"), and verify that the *CommonName* is "MarkLogic Ops Director Certificate Authority"

If all of that checks out correctly, then you can try unmanaging the cluster then manage the cluster again.  If you run into any errors in this process, check the MarkLogic KB on [Ops Director Troubleshooting](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/649/0/ops-director-troubleshooting).

Comment: This is what helped 
In this case it looks like the certificate that Ops Director is attempting to use to authenticate against the managed server is not correct.
So in our case, it was machine new name was regenerated as VM was created again